# Determine the shortest distance travelled to pass through every path once and return to the starting position

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

A $5 \times 4$ lattice points are all connected to represent possible paths. Each path is exactly $1$ meter long. Determine the shortest distance (in meters) a person needs to travel so that the person walks through each path at least once and returns to the starting position.

[image]

So quite clearly the minimum the distance has to be is $31$ meters (the sum of all the edges' lengths). And by trying out some paths I was able to figure out $38$ meters is the min. possible distance travelled, but I was wondering if there was a more 'mathematical' way because my way took a lot of time.

Comment: Note: This is a particular instance of the [Chinese postman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem).

Answer (score 2):

If all vertices had even degree a Eulerian circuit through the graph would exist. The question therefore is: How can we double a minimal number of edges such that all vertices obtain even degree?

Since there are $10$ vertices of odd degree we need at least $5$ additional edges. You have found a solution with $7$ additional edges; therefore the solution is one of $5$, $6$, or $7$.

I could not do better than $7$ myself.

Answer (score 0):

Notice there are more than two vertices of odd degrees. The graph is not even semi-Eulerian. So to find the distance, we have to compare the distances of pairing of odd vertices. In this case it's easier because the given graph is a grid with equal weights.

For the bottom 3 points, that are odd, the minimum pairing that connects these points is obviously $2$ meters. For the 2 points on the leftmost side, the minimum pairing is $1$ meters. By symmetry, the minimum sum of distances of pairs of odd vertices is $6$. Adding to the sum of all the edges' lengths gives $31+6=37.$